# Finding the dimensions of a stair on a round staircase

Tags: geometry

I wasn't too sure how to word this, but I'm going to do my best. Today, I was given a challenge math problem by my teacher. It was off the top of his head and riddled with errors, forcing me to set some of my own dimensions. It confused him.

On a round staircase, given a step and a pole for the center, how can you find the radius of the circle and all missing dimensions?

[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U793t.png)

When given the problem, I was supposed to find the dotted line that is labeled 11.351. I used Inventor to solve it myself because I couldn't find a way to do it without the aid of software. I was originally not even given the degrees of the end step arc, but after asking a few questions, I was allowed to set it myself. I made it 15 degrees.

With this given information, how would I solve this without using Inventor? It's been bugging me. I hate not knowing how to solve a problem that I know can be solved. I would love for there to be a convenient formula for me, but there  probably isn't.

How would I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you still need help on this one?

Comment: I would like help on this. It was awhile ago, but it would still be nice to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the drawing below find UB (using sin function with KU) and since you know the radius - 6.000, the location of C, the center of the circle.
Now you may find BP by the cos equation for triangles. From this you calculate BM, the radius for the edge of the step.
Note: MN is not needed and may be calculated with BM, using sin function.

Let me know if this was good enough for you to conclude the calculations.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, thanks! Helped a ton. I know that there's an answer to it somewhere once I figure it out without the help of a program, but I at least get it now.

Comment: Sorry, new to the site

Comment: We all learn with time:) Do you have anything else we could help you with?